# Appium IDE not starting and displaying an error- "Error ECONNRESET"

Tags: appium

System info:

```
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
Appium commandline version: 1.7.2
Appium IDE version: Version 1.3.1 (1.3.1)
Appium IDE location: /Applications Folder
npm version: 3.10.10
Node version: v6.10.0
```

Whenever I try to open a new session using Appium IDE, I am getting error:

> Error ECONNRESET

I am having older version of Appium IDE Version 1.5.3 (Ara) - and it works fine.
Also note that- at the time of trying to open new Appium IDE, old IDE is kept closed.

[image]

Comment: even after adding all Appium IDE updates, I am still facing same issue. I have tried removing Appium runtime & reinstalling it but no affect.

Comment: Just would like to see if anybody has a solution on this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed.
Installed all updates for Appium Desktop (1.5.0)
Toggled the port once from 4723 to 4724 (on host 127.0.0.1) in inspector mode.
Once Inspector mode was up and running, shut down the appium IDE.
reset the port to 4723(on host 0.0.0.0) and Inspector started.
Also verified that older version of Appium IDE (Appium IDE Version 1.5.3 (Ara) ) is still working.